# Remove "Array ( [] =>" in PHP

Tags: php

So I have this PHP script that fetches random quotes from a database. That works all fine, however, the result is printed like this:

```
Array ( [quote] => I'm not a real programmer. I throw together things until it works then I move on. The real programmers will say "Yeah it works but you're leaking memory everywhere. Perhaps we should fix that." I’ll just restart Apache every 10 requests. )
```

How ugly! How do I remove the `Array ( [quote] =>` and just print the string?

My PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `quote` FROM `qutoes` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: `echo $row['quote'];`?

Comment: too general....print_r will show it like that (Though your array is invalid).  read up on how `echo` arrays

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a variable handling function. It's intended to tell you about the variable, not to simply display its contents.

Comment: The duplicate assigned/referenced above is a very poor choice.

Comment: This wasn't a duplicate at all but okay